# Start application and close it after delay?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to run a simple script in LinuxMint to open application sqlitebrowser, to stay open for 5 seconds and close it, or kill it,
I tried this, but it doesnt close it:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
sqlitebrowser /home/r/base.db -t users
set -e
sleep 5
sqlitebrowser -q
exit
```

I also tried with `kill sqlitebrowser`, `killall sqlitebrowser`, exit but it doesnt work. I also tried wit ID, `kill $9011`.
I browse through many threads but couldnt find solution so far.

Comment: What happens with `timeout 5s sqlitebrowser /home...` ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-kill

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

xcalc &
processId=$! # get process id of xcalc

sleep 5
kill $processId
```

Here, I start `xcalc` and forks it with `&`, then I get the process id of `xcalc`, `sleep` five seconds and then kill the process of `xcalc`.